# Running commands via root on SSH2

Tags: php, linux, ssh

I am developing a control panel in PHP, i have the PHPsecLib libraries installed and am using it to issue commands to the remote servers.

For example;

```
$ssh->exec("cd /home/{$user}/{$id}; screen -S {$id} -A -d -m  java -Xmx768M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui -nojline;");
```

Now my question is, because i am issuing the commands as root, is this a security threat, even when all the commands that are ran, are pre-made/hard coded and not from user inputs.

If this is an issue, could anyone advise the best way of doing it?

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not want to run as root. Rather, to harden the platform a bit if you are using sudo:

```
username    ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/screen, PASSWD: ALL
```

This would allow your user: `username` to run screen without the need of sudo/password, but still require authentication for the rest of the executables on the platform.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you another way :

1/ your php does not execute commands, but write them to a file

2/ a croned php file or a daemon checks this file regularily and execute commands as root.

Never be confident in your UI, even if you are using static things to run commands.

Comment: So would it be better if the server owners account was to run the command with a very limited SSH account.

Comment: Yes of course, if your commands do not do advanced system commands, you should avoid using root account.

Comment: This is by far most the most preferable way to perform what you are trying to do, Rather than using root through php

Comment: My issue is that, if i run the command from the user, this means it needs SSH access, but i don't want to user to have SSH access, i can't see a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do sudo with phpseclib as discussed here:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#sudo

Answer (score 0):

There is one way:

NEVER run commands as root.

It's a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for your completely useless advice

Comment: another 'root' tricycle rider who doesn't know anyone with physical access to the machine can change the root password any time they like - linux is a emulation of Unix, which has always had this